# Plotting glitch with matplotlib [python3]? - EDITED

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I have some issues plotting "large" datasets of timeseries data in python, where the time jumps across a few decades in erroneous samples. We aim to visualise only the timestamp (unixtime + custom microseconds) vs index. In this example there are roughly 40k samples.

Basically, I am assuming it is some issue with the rendering of the plot by matplotlib, because when I move the axes, both the scatter points and also the lineplot seem to glitch all over the place. A further bit of evidence for this is that the line in the lineplot is not actually going through the markers, when I zoom in or pan the plot.

**The timestamps are continuous and increase by 40ms between steps.**

[Overview of errors (timestamp is zero -> default date 1.1.1970)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0D6V.png)

[Zoomed in on y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EVWJ.png)

[More zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh8cw.png)

[Example of how the plot should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDhHU.png)

[Timestamp raw data (ignore ms fraction 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y6ok.png)

Code used to plot (using google colab, re-created in Visual Studio Code)

```
  if single_file_or_multiple == "multiple":
    fig = px.line(df_trace, x=df_trace.index, y="time", markers=True,
                  color="rec_id")
    fig.show()
```

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't have any rendering issue of that sort. You have outliers in your data and since you chose to draw lines and markers, you get lines between consecutive markers.

Comment: Thats the thing, the lines are not between markers, as the horizontal lines you can see in the images are the "lines" from matplotlib and the diagonals are the markers, which cannot be?

Comment: Really hard to tell what the issue is, but unixtime+custom microsecond sounds like a good place to look for errors. Also note you are using pandas and their time converters, which bypass matplotlibs.

Comment: @JodyKlymak seems unlikely, as the timestamps are correct, i.e. the increase monotonously by 40ms between samples.

Comment: Again, we can only really guess what your issue is.  You should isolate it and give a reproducible example here.  I'm not particularly following why you are plotting index versus timestamp here, but it definitely indicates that your timestamps are either to ordered or being interpreted by pandas as not ordered.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also note that you are using `px.` which might indicate that you aren't using matplotlib at all, but rather [plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/). It's hard to tell without reproducible code and data. Anyway, the glitch is in your data, not in matplotlib nor plotly. 40K points is in no way considered large.